# Question mark box instead of my Mac name in Terminal

Tags: terminal, font, iterm, file, defaults

I'm normally using iTerm2, but lately I wanted to restore its settings because of a style that I didn't like, so what I did, was run the command which I've found in [Re-setting iTerm on MacOS X](https://superuser.com/questions/10309/re-setting-iterm-on-macos-x)

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist
```

It successfully removed the file, but then the question mark box started to appear instead of every symbol.

What can I do to fix it?

[image: Screenshot of a Terminal window with question mark boxes as instead of the username]

Comment: This looks like a font issue. How is the prompt string defined in your shell?

Comment: @nohillside how do i find it ?

Comment: It's defined in one of the init files of your shell (probably bash or zsh, so .bashrc, .zshrc and similar).

Comment: @nohillside im not sure i understand it correctly, but should it be something like this:
ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k" ?

Comment: If you use a theme, it may require some special fonts. This should be mentioned in the documentation though.

Comment: @moses Did you try the answer from the linked post that had the highest number of upvotes, i.e. `defaults delete com.googlecode.iterm2.plist`. I agree that this looks like a font issue, but it might be worth a try as simply deleting preference files rarely works anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the documentation for `powerlevel10k` (specifically [this part](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k#icons-glyphs-or-powerline-symbols-dont-render)), you need to install the appropriate font. That directs you to this [other part](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k#meslo-nerd-font-patched-for-powerlevel10k) of the documentation to find the font and installation methods you need to fix the issue.

Comment: thanks, i did what was requested there and it fixed the problem